# Passing JavaScript variables between files

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I have successfully taken input data from a form and output it as console.log('input') in setting.html. But how do I send this variable to another file called index.html?

Here is setting.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>settings></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action=index.html>
    <input id="userinput" type="text">
    <button onclick="myfunction()">Click me</button>
    </form>
  </body>
  <script>
    var theinput='';
    function myfunction() {
    theinput=document.getElementById("userinput").value;
  console.log(theinput);
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

and index.html is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="settings.html"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
<a href="setting.html">settings</a>

    <button onclick="theFunction()">generate pdf</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script>
input=document
function theFunction() {
var num = 'this is....';
console.log(num);
  const pdf = new jsPDF();
  pdf.text(num,10,10);
  pdf.save('a4.pdf');
}
</script>
</html>
```

### Updated

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
<a href="setting.html">settings</a>

    <button onclick="theFunction()">generate pdf</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script>
input=document
function theFunction() {
var num = 'this is....';
console.log(num);
  const pdf = new jsPDF();
  pdf.text(num,10,10);
  pdf.save('a4.pdf');
  //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
   let userInput = localStorage.getItem("userinput") || "";
   console.log(userInput);
</script>
</html>
```

setting.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>settings></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Settings</h1>
    <form>
            <input id="userinput" name="input" type="text">
            <button type="button" class="btn-submit">Submit</button>
        </form>

    <script>
    let btn = document.querySelector(".btn-submit")
    let userinput = document.querySelector("#userinput")
    btn.addEventListener("click",function(){
      localStorage.setItem("userinput",userinput.value)
      location.href = "index.html";
    });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: where is index.html stored?  what are you using for your backend?

Comment: index.html and setting.html are both in the same directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in settings capture your submit button's click and set a localStorage item value to the user input. Then redirect the user to the index.html file

```
    <form>
        <input id="userinput" name="input" type="text">
        <button type="button" class="btn-submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

<script>
let btn = document.querySelector(".btn-submit") 
let userinput = document.querySelector("#userinput") 
btn.addEventListener("click",function(){
  localStorage.setItem("userinput",userinput.value)
  location.href = "index.html";
});
</script>
```

Then in index.html you can access that variable like below. The **|| ""** says if userinput doesn't exist in localStorage, use "" as the default value;

```
<script>
   let userInput = localStorage.getItem("userinput") || "";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways through which this can be achieved.

1. Using localStorage is one option. You can use the setItem and getItem functions in the settings.html and index.html respectively to get the value like so (on a high level):

```
localStorage["key"] = value;

... in another page ...
value = localStorage["key"];
```

2. jQuery load function. You can look into its documentation - pretty simple.
3. Through URI encoding as follows:

In the file from where you want to send:

```
var b = document.getElementById('name').value,
        url = 'http://path_to_your_html_files/next.html?name=' + encodeURIComponent(b);

    document.location.href = url;
```

And in the file where you want to receive:

```
var url = document.location.href,
        params = url.split('?')[1].split('&'),
        data = {}, tmp;
    for (var i = 0, l = params.length; i < l; i++) {
         tmp = params[i].split('=');
         data[tmp[0]] = tmp[1];
    }
```

All three options could be extended to work with multiple variables as well!

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for this Altaf I just need to pass the variables in an object and pass that object to local storage.